# XSLT how to create one string with more elements in hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have this XML source:

```
<HEADER>
      <ODL_CODE>589146586</ODL_CODE>
      <ADR_CODE>154116515</ADR_CODE>
      <MNV_HER>EUR</MNV_HER>
      <IKS>
         <TYPE_CU>BY</TYPE_CU>
         <ID_CU>549745</ID_CU>
         <NAME>Company name</NAME>
         <ADDRESS>Street 123, City</ADDRESS>
         <TEL>+45 789 632 548</TEL>
         <MAIL>mail@address.com</MAIL>
      </IKS>
      <IKS>
         <TYPE_CU>IV</TYPE_CU>
         <ID_CU>7894156</ID_CU>
         <NAME>Company name #2</NAME>
         <ADDRESS>Street 123, City #2</ADDRESS>
         <TEL>+45 789 632 548 #2</TEL>
         <MAIL>mail@address.com #2</MAIL>
      </IKS>
 </HEADER>
```

and I want to have this output:

```
 <HEADER>
      <ODL_CODE>589146586</ODL_CODE>
      <ADR_CODE>154116515</ADR_CODE>
      <MNV_HER>EUR</MNV_HER>
      <IKS>
         <TYPE_CU>BY</TYPE_CU>
         <ID_CU>549745</ID_CU>
         <NAME>Company name</NAME>
         <ADDRESS>Street 123, City</ADDRESS>
         <TEL>+45 789 632 548</TEL>
         <MAIL>mail@address.com</MAIL>
      </IKS>
      <IKS>
         <TYPE_CU>IV</TYPE_CU>
         <ID_CU>7894156</ID_CU>
         <NAME>Company name #2</NAME>
         <ADDRESS>Street 123, City #2</ADDRESS>
         <TEL>+45 789 632 548 #2</TEL>
         <MAIL>mail@address.com #2</MAIL>
      </IKS>
      <POZN_1>Name: Company name #2, Street: Street 123, City #2, TEL: +45 789 632 548 #2</POZN_1>
 </HEADER>
```

How to write it in XSLT? I try concatenate function in "value-of select", but I have a problem with 2 elements in code TYPE_CU, ID_CU, etc.
It must be identification by "IV" in TYPE_CU, but I don't know why.

Comment: Can you edit your question with any XSLT you have tried? Also, can you explain what logic you are trying to implement? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the nature of the problem.  Is it about how to select the correct elements for building the value of `<POZN_1>`?  What does `concatenate()` have to do with it?  (And why, in fact, do you need `concatenate()` at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to show the code which you try to do for the concatenation of the values:

Use this code hope will help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="IKS[TYPE_CU='IV']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <POZN_1><xsl:value-of select="concat('Name: ' , NAME, ', Street: ', ADDRESS, ', TEL: ', TEL)"/></POZN_1>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```